# Why are fixed and absolute positioned elements considered block formatting context, but not a relatively positioned elements?

Tags: css, css-position

Why are fixed and absolute positioned elements considered block formatting context, but not a relatively positioned elements?

In simple words, What was in CSS concepts designers mind to make absolute and fixed positioned element a BFC while relative ones not?

Comment: @Obsidian Age 

do you think this edit makes my question more readable??

Comment: I don't know why but you can find the document : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Identifying_the_containing_block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say because `position:relative` doesn't change the behavior of the element like `absolute` and `fixed` will do. When setting an element with `absolute` and `fixed`, it will get removed from the flow. It's like you remove a fragment of the page to make it independent thus it need to establish a new block formatting contexts.

Whith `position:relative` it's different.

> Once a box has been laid out according to the normal flow or floated, it may be **shifted relative to this position**. This is called relative positioning.

then

> A relatively positioned box **keeps its normal flow size**, including line breaks and the space originally reserved for it.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning)</sup>

Basically, `position:relative` will keep the behavior of the element and will simply allow you to shift its position after being placed in the normal flow. You need to check the other properpties to see if the element will establish a BFC or not.

You may also note that `positon:relative` apply to inline element and inline element should not establish a BFC.